# How to compute number of ways one S and one F can be chosen from group of (2F, 2S, 2J, 2R)?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I thought I knew combinations pretty well, until recently I came across this question:

> In a high school debating team consisting of 2 freshmen, 2 sophomores,
>   2 juniors, and 2 seniors, two students are selected to represent the
>   school at the state debating championship. The rules stipulate that
>   the representatives must be from different grades, but otherwise the 2
>   representatives are to be chosen by lottery. What is the probability
>   that the students selected will consist one freshman and one
>   sophomore?

The way I approached this problem was to compute $\frac{N}{D}$, where

- $N =$ number of ways a sophomore and freshman can be chosen
- $D$ = total number of ways students can be chosen from different grades

The I broke it down as follows:

- $D$ = total number of ways to choose 2 students - number of ways to choose students from the same grade.
  So, $D = C(n=8, k=2) - 4 = 28 - 4= 24$
- $N$ = 1, because there is only one way to choose a sophomore and a freshman.

But this gets me $\frac{1}{24}$, which is incorrect.  I understand there are other ways of doing this problem, but I'm interested in knowing where I went wrong in my logic/approach of the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly calculated the denominator.  However, there are four ways to select a freshman and a sophomore since there are two ways to select a freshman and two ways to select a sophomore.  Hence, the probability that a freshman and a sophomore are selected for the competition is
$$\Pr(\text{selected students are a freshman and a sophomore}) = \frac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{8}{2} - \binom{4}{1}\binom{2}{2}} = \frac{4}{24} = \frac{1}{6}$$
assuming each individual is equally likely to be chosen.

Comment: Right...I realized this myself too.  In fact, there's an easier way to compute the denominator if you consider multiplying these two together:  1) number of ways to choose which two different grades to choose from = $C(4,2) = 6$, and 2) number of ways to choose the 2 individuals from those 2 grades = 4 (as you pointed out).  4*6 = 24.  thanks

Comment: @Sother  Good observation.